# can anyone Briefly explain the main difference between TCP Reno and TCP New Reno?

Tags: tcp

Briefly explain main difference (s) between TCP Reno and TCP New Reno (RFC 2582)?

Comment: www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee122/fa05/projects/.../SACKRENEVEGAS.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that TCP Reno can't distinguish between full ACK and partial ACK while new Reno can. Therefore multiple packet loss is detected by new Reno.

In context of protocol, TCP new Reno remains in the fast recovery until all the outstanding packets are acknowledged. But Reno remains in fast recovery until partial acknowledgment happens.